# Copy&Paste content into TinyMCE input results in bloated HTML

Tags: php, html, formatting, tinymce, copy-paste

I use TinyMCE for various projects. The problem I'm having ATM is that a lot of users copy&paste content form sources like Word or OpenOffice into the TinyMCE input. This results often in bloated code (e.g. things like `<span lang="EN-GB">` being taken over from OpenOffice). TinyMCE's cleanup doesn't seem to remove those tags. Is there a way to strip all formating *befor* the text is pasted into the TinyMCE input area? Or is there another way to prevent such bloated code, for example by filtring it server side with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove all tags using the followingc function on_preprocess:

```
strip_tags = function (str, allowed_tags) {
    var key = '', allowed = false;
    var matches = [];    var allowed_array = [];
    var allowed_tag = '';
    var i = 0;
    var k = '';
    var html = ''; 
    var replacer = function (search, replace, str) {
        return str.split(search).join(replace);
    };
     // Build allowes tags associative array
    if (allowed_tags) {
        allowed_array = allowed_tags.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gi);
    }
     str += '';

    // Match tags
    matches = str.match(/(<\/?[\S][^>]*>)/gi);
     // Go through all HTML tags
    for (key in matches) {
        if (isNaN(key)) {
            // IE7 Hack
            continue;        }

        // Save HTML tag
        html = matches[key].toString();
         // Is tag not in allowed list? Remove from str!
        allowed = false;

        // Go through all allowed tags
        for (k in allowed_array) {            // Init
            allowed_tag = allowed_array[k];
            i = -1;

            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<'+allowed_tag+'>');}           
            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<'+allowed_tag+' ');}
            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('</'+allowed_tag)   ;}

            // Determine
            if (i == 0) {                allowed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
         if (!allowed) {
            str = replacer(html, "", str); // Custom replace. No regexing
        }
    }

     return str;
};
```

In the tinymce init i place

```
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {

// remove Clipboard header on MAC
var pos_sel = o.content.search("EndSelection:");
var pos_fra = o.content.search("EndFragment:");
var mac_header_found = false;

if (o.content.search("Version:") == 0 && pos_sel < 135 && pos_sel > 120){
    o.content = o.content.substring(pos_sel+23);
    mac_header_found = true;
}
else if (o.content.search("Version:") == 0 && pos_fra < 80 && pos_fra > 75){
    o.content = o.content.substring(pos_fra+23);
    mac_header_found = true;
}

// Copy from Word oder OpenOffice (MAC) - remove header
if (o.wordContent || mac_header_found) {
    // first style tag + content to be removed
    var pos_start_style = o.content.search('<style');
    var pos_end_style = o.content.search('</style>');
    if (pos_start_style > 0 && pos_end_style > pos_start_style) {
        o.content = o.content.substring(0, pos_start_style).concat(o.content.substring(pos_end_style + 8));
    }
    // complete Worddokument gets pasted
    else {
        var pos_start_p = o.content.search('<p');
        if (pos_start_p) o.content = o.content.substring(pos_start_p);
    }
}

    o.content = ir.im.strip_tags( o.content, '' );

// NO-Break Zero-width space if empty
if (o.content == '') {
    o.content = '&#65279;';
}   
},
```

Comment: Looks great. Have to try it. So basically, if I've got it right, we define a function which filters all non white listed HTML elements, which is called through the tinyMCE init. Or have I got something wrong?

Comment: it is not called throught the init, but the function which will be called in case of paste (the pre_processing) is defined using the init

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an opd question but for the benefit of others who may be searching for an answer to this (like I was!), TinyMCE now includes the ability to control what is pasted into the textbox.

In the init call, add the "paste" plugin and then set whatever options you require, e.g.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    plugins: "paste",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
    paste_strip_class_attributes: "all",
    paste_remove_spans : true,
    ...
});
```

You can see all options in the [tinyMCE wiki](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x%3apaste)